# How to find a document that has any of these properties?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I need some kind of way to check if a document with any of x properties with same value exists in the database. Something like:

```
Group.findOne({
  name: "asd",
  url: "examp.le"
})
```

And the response being something like

```
{
  name: "asd",
  url: "not examp.le"
}
```

...or...

```
{
  name: "not asd",
  url: "examp.le"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
Group.findOne({
  $or: [{
    name: { $exists: true }
  }, {
    url: { $exists: true }
  }]
})
```

To build dynamic object

```
var filter1 = {}
var someDynamicPropertyName = 'name'
filter1[someDynamicPropertyName] = { $exists: true }

Group.findOne({
  $or: [filter1]
})
```

Comment: 1. this only checks if it exists, not the value
2. I want to just pass an object, as I'm getting the info from an HTTP request

Comment: 1. _if a document with any of x properties exists in the database_ from your question. 2. updated, use dynamic object

Comment: Updated, the example clearly shown that soo, instead of downvoting you could of edited it right?